# Increment database by 1, using UPDATE (mysql). What's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, database, increment

I try to write code that receive a student ID as an input in student_list.php, and pass this ID to score.php.

At score.php, use that ID to match and pull out student's name from database, and display it here.

Then, below the name, there is an input field, for adding 1 score to database for this student.

But I got this message, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

student_list.php

```html
<?php
  include_once 'DBconnect.php';
?>

<html>
  
  <head>Student List</head>
  
  <body>
    
    <form method="post" action="score.php">
 
 <?php 
  
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3") 
  or die(mysql_error());      
 
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>Student ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th> Button </th> </tr>";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['student_id'] . ' </td> ';     
    echo '<td>' . $row['student_fname'] . ' </td>';   
    echo '<td> <button type="submit" name="btn_student_id" value=" ' .  $row['student_id'] . ' "  >Select</button> </td>';    
    echo '</tr>'; 
      }      

  echo "</table>"; 

      ?> 
 
   </form>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

score.php

```html
<?php 

    include_once 'database_connect.php';

?>

<html>
  <head>Add Score</head>
  
  <body>

    <?php 

      $student_id = $_POST["btn_student_id"];

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3 WHERE student_id=".$_POST['btn_student_id'])
  or die(mysql_error());   
 
   echo "<table border='1'>";
   echo "<tr> <th>Student ID</th> <th>First Name</th> </tr>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['student_id'] . ' </td> ';      
    echo '<td>' . $row['student_fname'] . ' </td>';   
    echo '</tr>';  
     }      

     echo "</table>"; 
 
        if(isset($_POST['btn_add_score'])) {
  
          $score = $_POST['score'];  
   
          mysql_query ("UPDATE term3 SET score = score + 1 WHERE student_id = ' ".$_POST['btn_student_id']. "  ' ");  

        }  

    ?>

    <form method="post">
   <table>
  <tr>
       <td>Score</td>
    <td> <input type="number" name="score" size="8">
      <button type="submit" name="btn_add_score" >Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>  
   </table> 
    </form>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

```html
    ----------------------------------------
    Student ID  | Name  | Select           |
    ----------------------------------------
    10001       | Pat   | Button (submit)  |
    ----------------------------------------
    10002       | Jess  | Button (submit)  |
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: A sidenode: There are spaces in your update query. Additionally, there is no need to escape numbers with quotes in MySQL. Furthermore, please go ahead and read a tutorial about `mysqli` (mysql has been deprecated ages ago) and binding.

Comment: Your queries are open for SQL Injection. Never use input data directly in your queries. Always escape inputs correctly, or preferably use prepared statements.

Comment: well your sql is vulnereble to sql injection, you should sanitize your input, you can do it by using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function on php or using  prepared statements in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Rewrite the code when you test it and put the SQL into a string like this: `$sql = 'UPDATE term3 SET score = score + 1 WHERE student_id = ' . intval( $_POST['btn_student_id'] );` and the query: `$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error() . ' SQL:' . $sql);`. Now you can see the SQL and run it in phpmyadmin and test it. Once everything works, remove $sql from the die statement.

Comment: Which SQL is causing the error and please show us the table!

Comment: I think (but not sure) the UPDATE in if(isset) causes the error. Because before I added it to my code, everything was working fine. It was showing the list of all student IDs and names.

Comment: I tried the mysql_real_escape_string, but it didn't work. Maybe I put it in the wrong place? Where should I put it at?

Comment: You can use intval instead of mysql_real_escape_string, since you are passing a number. Try showing the SQL code, not working. I had an example above!

Comment: This should work: `'UPDATE term3 SET score = score + 1 WHERE student_id = ' . intval( $_POST['btn_student_id'] );`. I do believe you added some spaces before and after the id (" id "), making it look like a string!

Comment: Thank you. But it gives me a syntax error in my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotation marks around the student id in the update query. It is redundant

```
UPDATE term3 SET score = score + 1 WHERE student_id = ".$_POST['btn_student_id']);
```

Comment: Either way should work. Integers doesn't need to be in quotes. But you should never, under any circumstance, use user input directly in the query like this example shows

Comment: The problem is a space before and after the id in the quotation marks like " id " instead of just "id"!

Answer (score -4):

Update

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3 WHERE student_id=".$_POST['btn_student_id'])
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3 WHERE student_id='".$_POST['btn_student_id']."'")
```

Comment: While this might work or not (numbers do not necessarily be escaped with quotes), it is always better to say _why_ the OP should use your answer.

Comment: Both should work. Like @Jan said, integers doesn't need to be in quotes. But you should never, under any circumstance, use user input directly in the query like this example shows.